# How to check exact values in linq

Tags: c#

i have list like this

```
Porfolio Value  CumulativeWeights 
1246.540179      0.30873%
1254.380054      0.33031%
1258.260394      0.57136%
1262.300797      4.98794%
1262.710843      5.07213%
```

First:  if that list contains first value is greater than 5% select That value and 
Second: i have to check list contains exact 5% select That value.
if not satisfy above two condition we do some calculations. so how to select.

ConfidenceValue  is 5%

```
private static double CaluculateInterpolation(List<AgeWeightedHistorical> Weights, Double ConfidenceValue, CalaculationSettings oCalcSettings)
{
    double interpolation=0;

    var CumulativeVal = Weights.Find(n => n.CumulativeWeights > ConfidenceValue);
    if (CumulativeVal.CumulativeWeights >= ConfidenceValue)
    {
        interpolation = CumulativeVal.ProfolioPrices;
    }
    else 
    {
        var LowestValues = Weights.Last(n => n.CumulativeWeights <= ConfidenceValue);
        if (LowestValues.CumulativeWeights == ConfidenceValue)
        {
            interpolation = CumulativeVal.ProfolioPrices;
        }
        else
        {
            var HightValues = Weights.FirstOrDefault(n => n.CumulativeWeights >= ConfidenceValue);
            double avgPrices = (LowestValues.ProfolioPrices + HightValues.ProfolioPrices) / 2;
            double avgWeights = (LowestValues.CumulativeWeights + HightValues.CumulativeWeights) / 2;
            if (avgWeights == ConfidenceValue)
            {
                interpolation = LowestValues.ProfolioPrices;
            }
            else
            {
                double Lowest_val = Math.Abs(LowestValues.CumulativeWeights - ConfidenceValue);
                double Higest_val = Math.Abs(HightValues.CumulativeWeights - ConfidenceValue);
                var FinalWeight = (Lowest_val < Higest_val) ? LowestValues : HightValues;
                double minWeight = Math.Min(avgWeights, FinalWeight.CumulativeWeights) / 100;
                double maxWeight = Math.Max(avgWeights, FinalWeight.CumulativeWeights) / 100;
                interpolation = avgPrices - ((avgPrices - FinalWeight.ProfolioPrices) * (((1 - (oCalcSettings.PercentageLevelOfConfidence / 100)) - minWeight) / (maxWeight - minWeight)));
            }
        }
    }
    return interpolation;

}
```

im geting error please help me

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting ?

Comment: not getting correct values

Comment: Perfect problem description! 10/10

Comment: What is the expected output, please, and why?

Comment: cumulativeWeights[0] > 5 and CumulativeWeight[i] == 5 then Select related portfolio value

Answer (score 1):

I suggest in C#, for precision calculation you should be using

```
decimal
```

This will avoid many rounding problems..

Replace all your **double** with **decimal**, check your algorithm and it should work.